# Module not found (webpack)/hot/emitter @angular-devkit/build-angular after ionic serve - Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, webpack

Stack:

- node v10.15.1
- ionic 4.10.1

When I run `ionic serve` I get:

> ERROR in (webpack)/hot/emitter.js [ng] Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'events' in
>   '/zazou/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/hot'

Failed to compile.

Couldn't find an answer for this.

I tried to:

- update @angular-devkit/build-angular
- `npm install webpack-hot-dev-clients`
- `npm install -g webpack` and `npm install -g webpack-dev-server` as suggested [here](https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/12)
- `npm link wepack`
- I also tried to update my angular CLI

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107073/cannot-resolve-module-webpack-hot-emitter-while-using-hot-reloader)

Comment: try this: https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/12#issuecomment-129318103

Comment: look at my edit ..

Comment: delete your node_module folder and run `npm install` command.

Comment: It does not work sir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install events using npm.

```
npm install events
```

Or to save other people (e.g. repository users), run:

```
npm install events --save --dev
```

Comment: Your comment helped us on an Angular 7 project. Though events weren't being used anywhere, we added as devDependencies since it wasn't running without it. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this not installed with webpack if it's required?

Answer (score 2):

(same pb with angular 7, using angular/cli)

I don't have THE solution (as I don't really understand the issue), but after a lot of tries, it worked, so let me describe what I did, maybe it'll help you...

- swicth to node 9.5.0 (used n to do it)
- switching to npm 5.6.0
- remove global webpackage (I installed it for a try to solve version..)

  npm uninstall webpack -g
- rm -rf node_modules
- npm install
- then an issue with rxjs-compat, so I installed the version 6.4.0 for rxjs and rxjs/compat

Then it worked...
Maybe executing one of these steps will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this (when updating to Angular 11). To fix I had to:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
```